# appendTo element after its clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Here is my js:

```
$('ul li div').hide();
$('ul li a').click(function(){
    var nextUp = $(this).next();
    if ($('.infobox').is(':empty')) {
        nextUp.appendTo('.infobox').slideToggle(400);
    } else {
        $('.infobox').empty();
        nextUp.appendTo('.infobox').slideToggle(400);
    }
});
```

and the HTML/working example is here: http://jsbin.com/ajizeh/3#

I'm trying to append content that is in the div after the link and append it to  `.infobox`. It's half working though, it works the first time being clicked, but then if you click again, nothing appears. Also, the hiding when being clicked again isn't smooth like when it's showing.

So how can I get this to work, after clicking on another element.. let it show again, even after it's has been clicked once, also how do let the hiding be more smoothly?

Comment: You should pay more attention to code formatting next time.

Comment: Why would you append an element to the `.infobox` elements when the next thing you're going to do is empty the `.infobox` elements?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: He/she has provided one on http://jsbin.com, which is very easy for you to play with (in fact, for me it's usually a lot easier than http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I withdraw my comment about jsfiddle. My bad :-(

Comment: Oh sorry, I was messing around and didn't thought of formatting right away.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oops, mistake. empty before it's being appended to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUXnk/1/)

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li div').hide();

    $('ul li a').click(function() {
        var nextUp = $(this).next().clone();

        if ($('.infobox').is(':empty')) {
            nextUp.appendTo('.infobox').slideDown(400);
        } else {
            if (nextUp.html() != $('.infobox').children().html()) {
                $('.infobox').slideUp(400, function() {
                    $('.infobox').empty();
                    nextUp.appendTo('.infobox');
                    $('.infobox').children().show();
                });
                $('.infobox').slideDown(400);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I changed the var `nextUp` to be clone of the div because if you just append the div to somewhere else on the page it moves it. So when you were trying to append it again, it was no longer there.

For the smooth slideUp I emptied the `.infobox` after the slide up was completed. That way it didn't just disappear.

Comment: ahh, clone makes since. Any reason why use .on() then .click()?

Comment: There was no particular reason. I was just experimenting with it and forgot to change that back to click. My bad :)

Comment: Is it possible to not do anything if the same link has been clicked again? (For exammple, clicking on the same link in your example shows/hides it again)

Comment: You could try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qUXnk/3/). It assumes that the content of the divs will be different. So if the content is the same, it won't do anything.